# изменить код python для бота телеграм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

пишу код бота, который будет пересылать сообщения(фото, текст) написанные боту, на канал, в данный момент бот пересылает только тект, остальные игнорит(сообщения текст с видео/фото), нужно что бы пересылал как минимум фото и текст
буду благодарен

текущий код

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message.text)
```

Comment: Тебе тут никто не будет писать готового бота. Попытайся самому его сделать, а после задай вопрос по твоей проблеме.

Comment: Нужно создать еще одну функцию с декоратором, ловящим фото, ```@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать данный код:

```
bot.send_photo(photo=open('Ваш путь'))
```